# Handle click event for appended elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, onclick, append

I have generated few elements in my page using following method. For example,

```
$("#button"+caption).click(function(){
        var firstDisplay = '<div id="firstDisp'+caption+'"><ul>';
        for(var i=0;i<parents.length;i++){
            firstDisplay=firstDisplay+'<li class="fClick">'+parents[i]+'</li>';
        }
        firstDisplay=firstDisplay+'</ul></div>';
        $(firstDisplay).dialog();
});
```

and when i create an onclick event for 'fClass' like so :

```
$(".fClick").click(function(){
    alert("hey!");
});
```

It does not works ! However, if i put the onclick function inside the other function, right after .dialog(), it works ! I have a lot of elements created this way, so I cannot put all onclick events in a single method. Is there any way around this? I am having the same problem with .append method as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery events doesn't work for appended elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856650/jquery-events-doesnt-work-for-appended-elements)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Change it to `.on` or `.delegate` based on the version of jQuery you are using..

**As of jQuery 1.7+**

```
$(document).on('click', '.fClick', function(){ 
    alert("hey!");
});
```

For older jQuery versions use delegate

```
$(document).delegate('.fClick', 'click', function(){
    alert("hey!");
});
```

Comment: thanks man ! i knew i had to use delegates but was not sure where to attach it !

Comment: $(document).on('click', '.fClick', function(){ 
    alert("hey!");
}); this one is working well to me . thanks @Vega

Answer (score 1):

Use `on` instead of `click`:

```
$(".fClick").on('click',function(){
  alert("hey!");
});
```

`click` adds click handlers to `.fClick` elements that are present when you call `$('.fClick').click({...})`. New `.fClick` elements added later won't have the click event. But when you use `on`, all `.fClick` elements will have a click handler, even if they are added later.
Read more here:  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: `live` is deprecated, the recommended method now is `.on()`.

Comment: from http://api.jquery.com/live/ `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().`

Comment: Abraham, it is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

call the $(document).ready(function() again and add your code there.
The document gets read (refreshed) again and you can just apply your code there.

Answer (score 0):

What Vega has said is completely working.
There is a hint :
I think in the second line there is a mistake.
Probably you can use addClass method because you can't put id or class in rendering.
Here is an example:

```
var content = "<div>Hello, World</div>";
$("div").after(content);
$("last:div").addClass("mydiv");
```

And the class will be added but I am not sure that you can add an id.

Answer (score 0):

$('#element').append('Close');

```
$(document).on('click', '#close', function() {
      // This will work!
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).