# JQuery selector not working from external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

1. I am using a library `jquery.peity.min.js` and loading it first.
2. Then I have `myscript.js` which uses the function in above library as follows.

   ```
   $(".donut-mult").peity("donut", {
     width: 82,height:82,
     innerRadius:35,
     fill: ["#2ac7d7", "#fff"]
   })
   ```

This `myscript.js` is loaded after `jquery.peity.min.js`.

3. Now I make ajax call to `sample.jsp`.
4. `sample.jsp` has a span as follows

   ```
   <span class="donut-mult">5/5</span>
   ```

The javascript function in `myscript.js` is not getting bound to this span class and hence I cannot see the expected visualization.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Delegated event handlers !

Comment: here make sure your script `$(".donut-mult").peity("donut", { width: 82,height:82,innerRadius:35,fill: ["#2ac7d7", "#fff"] })` is executed after the `sample.jsp` is loaded

Comment: @adeneo looks like it is a plugin initialization...

Comment: @ArunPJohny - oh yeah, I just read *"ajax ... doesn't work on new elements"*

Comment: Here is the answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400343/jquery-binding-events-to-dynamically-loaded-html-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make a jquery selection before loading contents via ajax it will not work because they don't yet exist in the document. You need to load the content first before calling any functions that uses those html elements.

Use this code in your myscript.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // The container where you will load the content of sample.jsp
    var $container = $('#donut-container'); 

    // Load via ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: 'sample.jsp',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            // load sample.jsp content to the container
            $container.html(data); 

            // process the spans with class="donut-mult" loaded in the container
            // you can also use $('#donut-container .donut-mult').peity(...) 
            // instead of `$container.find`
            $container.find('.donut-mult').peity("donut", {
                width: 82,height:82,
                innerRadius:35,
                fill: ["#2ac7d7", "#fff"]
            })  
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: I had already tried this and I dont know why but that does not work